# How to plot Spectrogram of SoundNote?

Tags: plotting, sound

I try to use the expression:

```
Spectrogram[Sound[SoundNote[{"C", "E", "G", "C5"}, 10, "Vibraphone"]]]
```

to plot the spectrogram of a SoundNote. But Spectrogram symbol do not support SoundNote.
I tried Play and EmitSound but they all do not work. I think Spectrogram need a list of raw bytes of sound, how can I convert SoundNote sound to raw bytes?

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that `SoundNote` generates a MIDI event so I believe the sound will need to be played by the (operating) system and recorded, or otherwise converted with a software synthesizer.  I don't know how to do this from within *Mathematica* but I shall think about it.  Possibly useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FluidSynth

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Can we do anything useful with [this](http://pastebin.com/DK9d4fdd)?

Comment: @Sektor I am not familiar with that command but the output is probably still MIDI program data only in numeric form.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yup, it is; `Byte`. I was wondering if you were aware of some internal happy power :D

Comment: Thanks Mr.Wizard, Sektor. This is a good idea. 1.Export SoundNote to mid file. 2.Use software synthesizer generate wav file. 3. Import wav to MMA. The software synthesizer [TiMidity++](http://timidity.sourceforge.net/) can do this.

Answer (score 3):

```
sound = Sound[SoundNote[{"C", "E", "G", "C5"}, 10]];

data = First@AudioData@sound;(*get audio samples*)
sampleRate = AudioSampleRate@sound;(*get sampleRate*)
```

you can hear the sound again.

```
Sound@SampledSoundList[data, QuantityMagnitude[sampleRate]]
```

[image]

And you can view it spectrogram.

```
Spectrogram[data, 2048, SampleRate -> QuantityMagnitude[sampleRate]]
```

[image]

In short,you can use the code to deal with it.

```
 Spectrogram[First@AudioData@#, 2048, SampleRate -> QuantityMagnitude[AudioSampleRate@#]] &
     @Sound[SoundNote[{"C", "E", "G", "C5"}, 10]]
```

PS:

This code is shorter.

```
Spectrogram@Audio@Sound[SoundNote[{"C", "E", "G", "C5"}, 10]]
```