# Question as to whether or not the Mathematica IntegerReverse function applied to audio is working as it should

Tags: sound

I applied IntegerReverse[Round[Abs[10000000*(Audio[])]]] to an audio file in Mathematica to reverse the data set's digits, but I am unsure if it is doing what it should...

I know that using a different base and a different multiplier will alter the outcome of this function drastically.

When I applied this function I got static, crackling and intermittent white noise, and as I mentioned before, -just because the mind perceives a pattern in the audio-altering function, it dose not necessarily follow that the ear will.

Has anyone got any ideas for as to exactly how to test the hypothesis as to whether or not audio is being altered, absolutely and one hundred percent correctly?

Under this function, 459.102 should become something like: 2019, and 78.139 should become something like:9318.

Any comments, concepts, and ideas?

Please advise.

Comment: I have just been to see a friend who knows ONE HECK of a lot more about computing and computers than I do, and he tells me that audio files, and even *.wav files come in a great proliferation and variety of formats. He also tells me that he wants to help me with the "sound sample reversal of digits" thing, so, in due course, I will keep you people here at Mathematics Stack Exchange updated, and will also tell you (in due course), as to the results of our experiments with IntegerReverse on audio files. Many thanks.

Comment: Using https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/70107/how-to-plot-spectrogram-of-soundnote

`sound=Sound[SoundNote["C",1/10]];data=First@AudioData@sound` to see the numbers making up that sound and 
`bitreversedata=IntegerReverse[Round[Abs[10000000*data]]]` to see the numbers making up the bit reverse data makes me wonder. Test this very carefully, perhaps on even simpler pure tones of various amplitudes and frequencies, before you even think about trusting this. The answer I used for this also shows how you can play the resulting bit reversed data.

Comment: The problem as stated is not well defined. There is no clear guidance in your examples for how many digits to take or whether to round or truncate at the last one. The code will do what it is coded to do (tautologically), and it is up to you (not readers) to ascertain whether that meets with your expectation.

Comment: I recall the same or very similar question being asked on the Wolfram Community site a while back. It was deleted by the moderators, probably due to vagueness and lack of clarity.

Comment: Yes, I put it there. I moved it because it was suggested to me to start another topic, as we were getting a bit off topic. I only did what was suggested to me.

Comment: I had it suggested to me that I should start a new topic, so I did. I was only trying to abide by the rules.